# Including struct and compilation in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, struct, compilation, compiler-construction

I noticed that when compiling and linking code that includes a struct in a header file, the struct declaration is actually needed only for compiling. 
Say I have a struct.h file, I can replace it with an empty file between compiling and linking without any problem.

My question is : what exactly is doing the compiler ? I guess there must be a copy of the struct full declaration in each .o file using the structure and I wonder how it makes sure that it is always the same struct.

Bonus question : is there a way to redefine the struct before linking ?

Comment: This is so much unclear. `I can replace it with an empty file between compiling and linking` - linker uses object and libraries files, it does not use the source files. `I wonder how it makes sure that it is always the same struct.` - It doesn't. And that's when undefined behavior happens.

Comment: Can you share the exact cmd-line instructions used to perform such task?

Comment: Bonus question: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple aspects that I think are confusing you.  Fundamentally, structs are merely a way to map multiple related variables together in a block of memory.  So if you have a struct like:

```
struct x {
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

And then you use that struct, internally the compiler is really creating a memory spot for for the entire structure.  How big it is depends on the system, compiler, etc, but lets say an `int` is 4 bytes long (32-bits).  It's often the case that what the compiler is doing when you access `myvar.b` its really referencing 4 bytes into the memory location where myvar is stored.

But this is all done at compilation time where the compiler converts your C (or C++) code to an object file.  It doesn't actually store the struct itself into the object file, only the offsets it needs to access the memory portions.  Thus, linking doesn't require knowledge of the struct at all, which is why if you remove the struct from your .h during linking nothing changes: because the linker doesn't  even read that file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I understand correctly, the object file stores a map of the structure and if functions in the object file are given a struct variable with the same name, it will be read/written according to that map even if the struct was build in another file according to another map.

I think I got confused because, usually, I think of header files as a part of the code that is not compiled. Of course, there are some exceptions like inline functions but this is clearly highlighted when you are learning c/c++.